# No module named admin.sites.urls

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

I am new to Django, Python and this site. I have read the Django docs and the tutorial from " How to tango with django and now I hit a road block. I get an error No module names admin.sites.urls and not sure what I need to do now.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from rango import views
from django.contrib import admin, admindocs
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'rango.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^$', 'rango.views.about', name ='about'),
    url(r'^rango/', include('RangoTango.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.sites.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
) 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
    'django.views.static',
    (r'media/(?P<path>.*)',
    'serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.admindocs',
     'rango',

 )

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'RangoTango.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'RangoTango.wsgi.application'
```

Error:

```
ImportError at /admin

No module named admin.sites.urls

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    127.0.0.1:8000/admin
Django Version:     1.6.5
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named admin.sites.urls

Exception Location:     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 40
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

[
Server time:    Fri, 22 Aug 2014 18:44:18 +0000
```

Comment: I think it should be `admin.site.urls` (not sites).

Comment: @thebjorn Thank you for your correction. I am still learning how to post on this site. 
I changed it to admin.site.urls but now I get a different error. maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: You might want to open another question with for that problem. If you include some of the traceback will help someone figure out where things go wrong.

Comment: Ok Thank you. Right now I have to wait to ask a new quesitons since I am new to the site

Comment: What a pain :-)  If you don't want to wait you could possibly edit this question by adding the new problem to the end (so you don't invalidate Katerina's answer), but ideally wait and ask it as a separate question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thebjorn is right. Your urls.py should look more like this.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'tango.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  ## Here's the typo
    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
)
```

Comment: I changed it to admin.site.urls but now I get a different error. maximum recursion depth exceeded